# Controlling the styling of BootStrap form in Flask WTForms

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, wtforms

I have a form where there are 14 questions, 4 option for each question, 1 correct answer, and a timer field that has to be rendered on the page something like this:

[Expected form format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgLmr.png)

Help me in understanding and using WTFroms along with bootstrap to make my form look like this:

Currently, this is how it looks:

[Current form format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYcTv.png)

Code for `forms.py`:

```
class XMLQuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    question = FieldList(StringField('Question', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=395)]), min_entries=14, max_entries=14 )
    optionA = FieldList(StringField('Option A', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)]), min_entries=14, max_entries=14)
    optionB = FieldList(StringField('Option B', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)]), min_entries=14, max_entries=14)
    optionC = FieldList(StringField('Option C', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)]), min_entries=14, max_entries=14)
    optionD = FieldList(StringField('Option D', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)]), min_entries=14, max_entries=14)
    
    answer = FieldList(SelectField('Answer', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[(None,'<Select an answer>'),('Option A','Option A'),('Option B','Option B'),('Option C','Option C'),('Option D','Option D')]), min_entries=14, max_entries=14)
    timer = FieldList(IntegerField('Timer', default=60),  min_entries=14, max_entries=14)

    submit = SubmitField('Generate XML')
```

Code for `home.html`

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">KBC Question XML Creator</legend>
                {% for n in range(14) %}
                    <!-- Question -->
                    {% if form.question[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.question[n](class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.username[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.question[n].label }} {{ loop.index }} {{ form.question[n](class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 
                    {% endif %}

                    <!-- Options -->
                    {% if form.optionA[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.optionA[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.optionA[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.optionA[n].label }} {{ form.optionA[n](class="form-control col-sm-2") }} 
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if form.optionB[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.optionB[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.optionB[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.optionB[n].label }} {{ form.optionB[n](class="form-control col-sm-2") }} 
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if form.optionC[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.optionC[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.optionC[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.optionC[n].label }}  {{ form.optionC[n](class="form-control col-sm-2") }} 
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if form.optionD[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.optionD[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.optionD[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}                        
                        {{ form.optionD[n].label }} {{ form.optionD[n](class="form-control col-sm-2") }}                         
                    {% endif %}

                    <!-- Answer -->
                    {% if form.answer[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.answer[n](class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.answer[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.answer[n].label }} {{ form.answer[n](class="form-control col-sm-4") }} 
                    {% endif %}

                    <!-- Timer -->
                    {% if form.timer[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.timer[n](class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.timer[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.timer[n].label }} {{ form.timer[n](class="form-control col-sm-4") }} 
                    {% endif %}
                    <hr>
                {% endfor %}                    
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's grid system works based on a 12 column system.
So for example, if you had 2 elements you wanted to display in the same row and give both an equal amount of space, you would give each of them 6 of the columns, each.
e.g. ->

```
<div class="row>
    <h1 class="col-md-6">Hello</h1>
    <h1 class="col-md-6">World</h1>
</div>
```

In your case where you needed to split up 8 pieces (4 answer labels, and 4 form boxes), it gets a bit more complex.
Once you give a DIV a set amount of the columns, inside that div, you distribute it based on the 12 column system still, even if 12 are not actually available.

Let's look at how I solved it in the solution I sent you below.
I started with putting half of the elements nested inside a div with class "col-md-6 row"
And the other half with the same.
Now when we are looking inside one of those halves, the moment we are nested inside, we are distribute those 6 columns based on the 12 grid system again.
So for example I could have given each of the 4 elements 3 each, class="col-md-3".
But since it seemed that you wanted the form field a bit larger than the text field, I went w/ "col-md-4" for the form fields and "col-md-2" for the text fields.

Here is what the solution looks like on my end -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mesv.jpg

I had to throw together an entire application to solve this so I went ahead and threw it on github for you if you want to look at the code there -> https://github.com/CraftyClark/ontrolling-the-styling-of-bootstrap-form-in-flask-wtforms/tree/main/application

Cheers,

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">KBC Question XML Creator</legend>
                {% for n in range(14) %}
                    <div class="row col-md-10"> 
                        <!-- Question -->
                        {% if form.question[n].errors %}
                            {{ form.question[n](class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.username[n].errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.question[n].label }} {{ loop.index }} {{ form.question[n](class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <!-- start of options row -->
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <!-- Options -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 row">
                            {% if form.optionA[n].errors %}
                                {{ form.optionA[n](class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.optionA[n].errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    {{ form.optionA[n].label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    {{ form.optionA[n](class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}

                    
                            {% if form.optionB[n].errors %}
                                {{ form.optionB[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.optionB[n].errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    {{ form.optionB[n].label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    {{ form.optionB[n](class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        

                        <div class="col-md-6 row">
                            {% if form.optionC[n].errors %}
                                {{ form.optionC[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.optionC[n].errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    {{ form.optionC[n].label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    {{ form.optionC[n](class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        

                    
                            {% if form.optionD[n].errors %}
                                {{ form.optionD[n](class="form-control  is-invalid") }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.optionD[n].errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% else %}                        
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    {{ form.optionD[n].label(class="form-control-label") }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    {{ form.optionD[n](class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                                </div>                       
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                  
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of options row -->


                    <!-- Answer -->
                    {% if form.answer[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.answer[n](class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.answer[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.answer[n].label }} {{ form.answer[n](class="form-control col-sm-4") }} 
                    {% endif %}

                    <!-- Timer -->
                    {% if form.timer[n].errors %}
                        {{ form.timer[n](class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in form.timer[n].errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.timer[n].label }} {{ form.timer[n](class="form-control col-sm-4") }} 
                    {% endif %}
                    <hr>
                {% endfor %}                    
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It did the work. Great explanation for the code. Thank You.